# Can I place <script></script> inside <script></script>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I need to load a advert contained in a set of script tags inside some script tags is it possible ?

Comment: No you can't, but why would you want to?

Comment: use Javascript to add the script tag: `var el = document.createElement('script')` and then set `el.src = "http://whatever";` to load it.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a `<script>` HTML tag what is inside is treated as a quoted (literal) string, so the inner  `</script>` tag inside is treated as a closing tag rather than as a portion of the string. So you cannot directly use the tag inside a script section.

If you must, user2310289's approach is valid or you could also use string concatenation -
eg: 
`"</sc"+"ript>");`

Answer (score 0):

You could try some thing like

```
var x = '<' + '/script>'; // or
var x = '<\/script>';
```